# how to use background image using props using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is my code where i'm trying to pass object like{title,description,backgroundImg ....} to section component using props , I am getting all the key & value but when I use it on section component getting all data value instead of backgroundImg why..?

```
import React from "react";
import Section from "./Section";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <Section
          title="Model S"
          description="Order Online for Touchless Delivery"
          backgroundImg="model-s.jpg"
          leftButton="custom order"
          rightButton="existing inventory"
        />
        <Section
          title="Model Y"
          description="Order Online for Touchless Delivery"
          backgroundImg="../images/model-y.jpg"
          leftButton="custom order"
          rightButton="existing inventory"
        />

    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

to

```
import React from "react";
import DownArrow from "../images/down-arrow.svg";

const Section = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="Wrap"
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.backgroundImg})` }}
    >
      <div className="item_text">
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <p>{props.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <div className="item_buttom">
          <div className="leftButton">{props.leftButton}</div>
          <div className="RightButton">{props.rightButton}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={DownArrow} alt="svgImg" className="DownArrow" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Section;
```

My image folder path is "../images/..."

Comment: seems like your path is wrong w.r.t section component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import image in your home component.

Like

```
import sectionImage from "../images/image.jpg";
```

then pass the image like

```
<Section
    backgroundImg={sectionImage}
/>
```

Then it should work fine.